# Is there any evidence that Krishna means supreme RigVedic deities like Indra when he talks about "devatas conferring limited benefits"?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, vedic-gods

for example

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/7/verse/20

BG 7.20: Those whose knowledge has been carried away by material desires surrender to the celestial gods. Following their own nature, they worship the devatās, practicing rituals meant to propitiate these celestial personalities.

However, Rama himself prayed to RigVedic God Surya (Aditya Hridayam) before the final battle with Ravana.

Comment: Vedic, Puranic, and Vedantic "religions" are different. Let's accept it and move on.

Answer (score 3):

There is proof as according to these commentaries:

> Those who desire wealth? children? the (small) Siddhis? etc.? are deprived of discrimination. They devote themselves to other minor gods such as Indra? Mitra? Varuna? etc.?
> A part of the commentary by Swami Sivananda on Bhagavad Gita 7.20
>
> In order to fulfil these various kinds of desires they take refuge in, i.e., seek and worship, other divinities who are regarded as different from Me, such as Indra and others
> . A part of the commentary by Ramanuja on Bhagavad Gita 7.20

Thus is said herein that the Devatas refer to Indra etc.

Comment: What you have cited is argument, commentary, opinion - not evidence, @rajam .

Comment: @S K oh so u want scriptural reference? Or is it something else?